# Rotation animation in xml doesn't rotate on the middle

Tags: android, android-gui

This is my animation in xml, I tried with android:pivotX="50%" but still I do not get what I want. The point of rotation is wrong. I want the green line to rotate around the middle of the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0" android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:toDegrees="360" android:pivotX="0%" android:pivotY="0%"
    android:repeatCount="5"
    android:duration="5000" android:startOffset="0" />
```

I want to make animation like this:
[image]
the green line should rotate , and the rotation point should be the center of the screen. How can I do this ?

Comment: It's unclear what your current symptoms are, but it might be related to this issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22969

Comment: @Lukap shouldn't be both `android:pivotX` and `android:pivotY` set to `"50%"`

Answer (score -2):

Use a RotateAnimation, setting the pivot point to the centre of your image.

```
RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 350f, 15f, 15f);
anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
anim.setDuration(700);

// Start animating the image
final ImageView splash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash);
splash.startAnimation(anim);

// Later.. stop the animation
splash.setAnimation(null);
```